# Scala : Putting similar things together

Tags: scala

I am quite new to Scala Programming. I tried putting the similar things into a class and then need to invoke it from the driver.
Below is it what I finally ended up.

Is the way correct or should I follow a different approach ?

```
package com.cases

object Cases{   
   case class A(.....)   
   case class B(.....) 
 }


package com.utilities

object Utilities{   
  def utility1(...): ReturnType ={   }
  def utility2(...): ReturnType ={   } 
}

package com.driver

//Need to import these, in order to use the other two objects 
import com.utilities._ 
import com.cases._

object Driver{   
   main(){
     //call utility methods 
       val return = Utilities.utility1(....)   
   } 
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how will you use class A and B? Do you need an enum functionality from it?

Comment: I would map the output of a transformation in Spark to the given case classes. So just wanted to know whether this is the right way to do it ?